# Yii2 createurl with integer parameter

Tags: url, yii2, parameters

I got the error 
syntax error, unexpected '‌' (T_STRING)
that's my link

```
 <?php $url=Yii::$app->getUrlManager()->createUrl('admin/message/chat',array('idUser'=>$contact['id'])‌);?>
```

and inside the rules function i add the following link:

[['admin/message/chat/idUser/' => 'admin/message/chat']],

and my action's script looks like:

```
public function actionChat($idUser = null)
    {
        $searchModel = new MessageSearch();
        $dataProvider = $searchModel->search(Yii::$app->request->queryParams);

        return $this->render('index', [
            'searchModel' => $searchModel,
            'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
            '$idUser' => $idUser,

        ]);
    }
```

Comment: shiow the rest of your code ..

Comment: @scaisEdge i added it above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your error is in

```
'$idUser' => $idUser,
```

It should be

```
'idUser' => $idUser,
```

Answer (score 0):

Could be you missed some  closing } eg: at the end of an  action or at the end of the controller class

```
class MessageController extends Controller
{

    public function actionChat()
    {
        ......  
    }

}  // check for this
```